# images in upload directory after upgrading WordPress to 3.0

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I've developed a [WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-record-collection/) and it wordked well from WP 2.0 and up to WP 3.0rc1 (haven't tried rc2) but now with rc3 and milestone 3.0 a strange and irritating error appeared.

If you check out my [demo page](http://myrecordcollection.arvid.nu/demo/) you will se that none of the cover-images is working. they are in the same place as before but they can not be hotlinked or show up when i enter the correct url. if i move the img-directory from /wp-content/uploads/my-record-collection/ to /wp-content/uploads/ the images show up if i enter the url, but not if i move it back inside my "my-record-collection"-folder.

anyone know what change in rc3(or maybe rc2) that made this bug appear and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: Can you show your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Sure Pekka, it looks like this:


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm think that you have folder permissions problem,always have that kind of problem when there are permissionns involved,url is good but image doesn't show up,just double check your folder permissions.

Comment: It was a permissions problem. strange that permissions got changed on a upgrade. Perhaps it was because i used the auto updater?

Comment: Dont know what plugin is that auto updater,but I'm sure that he need to change permissions to update wordpress.I always update wp manual,and there are no problems for me.